# Terragrunt path resolution - locally referenced modules - splitting into multiple environments

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terragrunt

For business-related reasons, I am not able to split my infrastructure using versioned modules. As it is still beneficial to split the environments, and I would like to avoid the copy/paste root modules, which are basically just instantiation of child modules, over multiple directories, each representing its own environment, I would like to specify the source of root module in *terragrunt.hcl*

To make life easier, I have built a small part of the current infrastructure, just with a single module to speed up the development.

The current structure of the project looks like this:

```
├── config
│   ├── common.tfvars
│   └── terragrunt.hcl
├── environments
│   └── dev
├── infrastructure-modules
│   └── ecs
├── terraform-modules
│   ├── terraform-aws-ecr
```

All my infrastructure is described in `infrastructure-modules/ecs/*.tf` files, which are basically just instantiating child modules declared in `terraform-modules/terraform-aws-*/`.

With that, I can simply execute the terragrunt (terraform commands) from the `infrastructure-modules/ecs` directory.

To have a possibility to create the same environment in another account, I have introduced a new directory `environments/dev/eu-central-1/ecs` as shown on tree output from the root directory.

The `environments/dev/eu-central-1/ecs`, consists just of two files, *terragrunt.hcl* and *common.tfvars*.

I guess, that the usage of the *common.tfvars* is quite self-explanatory, where my *terragrunt.hcl* consists of `remote_state {}` and `terraform {}` blocks.

The important part of the terragrunt configuration file:

```
remote_state {}

terraform {
  source = "../../../../infrastructure-modules/ecs"

  {...}
}
```

Above I am basically referencing my root modules, declared in `infrastructure-modules/ecs/*.tf`. Where my root modules are instantiating child-modules declared in `terraform-modules/terraform-aws-*/`.

Child modules from `infrastructure-modules/ecs/*.tf` are instantianed like this:

```
module my_module {
  source = "../../terraform-modules/terraform-aws-*"

  {...}
}
```

In an ideal world, I would be able to execute terragrunt (terraform) commands from `environments/dev/eu-central-1/ecs` directory, but as I am using local (relative) paths, this is failing during the *initialization* of the modules, as the root module **my_module** loads the child module with following relative path:

```
module my_module {
  source = "../../terraform-modules/terraform-aws-*"

  {...}
}
```

This is causing a module instantiation in `environments/dev/eu-central-1/ecs` to fail as the relative path is different, based on parent module instantiation.

```
Initializing modules...
- my_module in 

Error: Unreadable module directory

Unable to evaluate directory symlink: lstat ../../terraform-modules: no such
file or directory
```

So far, according to the documentation, `path_relative_*`, should be able to return the relative path between the path specified in its include block and the current terragrunt.hcl, but the problem here is that I am not having any `include {}` block(s) within my `terragrunt.hcl` files and thus this approach doesn't works. Symlinks are the last option.

**EDIT**

If I inspect the `.terragrunt-cache/*` on path `environments/dev/eu-central-1/ecs` I can confirm that all the "root" modules have been downloaded(copied over) into cache directory.

However, the module is being instantiated like this, and it tries to fetch the actual modules (Terraform modules) from directory two levels above.

```
module my_modules {
  source = "../..//terraform-modules/terraform-aws-ecr"
```

So basically, I need to tell Terragrunt to download/fetch the modules from other path.

**EDIT 2:**

Inspecting .terragrunt-cache in the directory where I am running `init` shows, the the `terraform-modules` are never downloaded in the
`terraform-infrastructure/environments/dev/eu-central-1/ecs/.terragrunt-cache/`.

If I change my `terraform-infrastructure/infrastructure-modules/ecs/ecr-repos.tf`, from

```
module ecr_lz_ingestion {
  source = "../../terraform-modules//terraform-aws-ecr"

{<MODULE_ARGUMENTS>}
  }
}
```

to:

```
module ecr_lz_ingestion {
  source = "../../../../../../../../terraform-modules//terraform-aws-ecr"

{<MODULE_ARGUMENTS>}
  }
}
```

Terraform is able to initialize the child-modules as I have given a relative path to `terraform-modules/` in the directory root, which is obviously a workaround.

Somehow I am expecting the Terragrunt to download both directories, `terraform-modules` and `infrastructure-modules` for the relative paths in module instantiation to work.

Comment: Do you use double slash in module path?

Comment: I have tried with both `//` and without.

Answer (score 5):

Based off the additional information you provided, I understand that this is your current directory structure:

```
terraform-infrastructure
├── config
│   ├── common.tfvars
│   └── terragrunt.hcl
├── environments
│   └── dev
│       └── eu-central-1
│           └── ecs
│               └── terragrunt.hcl
├── infrastructure-modules
│   └── ecs
├── terraform-modules
│   ├── terraform-aws-ecr
│   
├── terragrunt.hcl
```

Notice the `terragrunt.hcl` in the parent directory that I added.

That `terragrunt.hcl` is considered the parent file and can include code that can be shared among other terragrunt files.

It can include something like this:

```
remote_state {}
```

In your `eu-central-1/ecs` folder, add the following to your terragrunt file:

```
include {
  // searches up the directory tree from the current terragrunt.hcl file 
  // and returns the absolute path to the first terragrunt.hcl
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}

  // using the path relative from the path stated in the include block
terraform {
  source = "${path_relative_from_include()}//infrastructure-modules”
}
```

This should keep relative pathing intact when child modules are instantiating.

**Edit**:

From your GitHub issue, it would be best to either move the double slash to somewhere the modules share a common path with. Either that or to just consolidate your modules into a single folder.

Comment: No there is no parent `terrragrunt.hcl`. However, in any case, Terraform fails as it can't resolve modules in `infrastructure/modules/ecs.

Comment: Could you add a parent terragrunt file to use it as an anchor?

Comment: What is the parent dir of the entire collection of folders?

Comment: I think that I see the point right now. The parent dir is `terraform-infrastructure` as I am having other docker related directories inside.

Comment: @AlanKis I updated my answer with a possible solution. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Have you tried deleting your local state and re-initializing ?

Comment: Always, and deleting the .terragrunt-cache. I was able to resolve the issue after opening an Github issue. https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt/issues/1324.Feel free to update the answer and I will happily accept it.

Comment: @AlanKis awesome! I’m glad everything worked out. All that matters is you’re able to solve your issue. Edited.

Comment: indeed, I found this guys blog:https://ftclausen.github.io/dev/infra/terraform-solving-the-double-slash-mystery/, just add a missing slash will fix it..